# ChannelFactory per socket?

Tags: java, netty

When listening from multiple sockets for incoming UDP datagrams, how many `ChannelFactory`, `ConnectionlessBootstrap` should be used? Only one? One per socket?

I precise that the decoding handler of the pipeline is different per socket. From one port I expect to receive SIP messages while I expect to receive DNS messages from another port.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

One NioDatagramChannelFactory per port that you want to listen too

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I've just found http://lists.jboss.org/pipermail/netty-users/2009-September/001232.html. It indicates that the bind() method may be called multiple times, or even that multiple bootstrap may be created. So, it seems that the same ChannelFactory may be used, am I right?